# HTML,JS change img src path

Tags: javascript, html, webserver, plc

I have two images named "Status1.png", "Status0.png" and tag from JavaScript "VarId3" which changing with 0/1.
 Is it possible to make something like this :

`<img  src="Images\Status"VarId3".png"/>`  //this actually don't work

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly. You want to dynamically change the image path.

Whatever is your logic for changing the name, based on that.

You can first create the image path name, like so:

```
let imagePath = 'Images\Status'+VarId3+'.png"
```

then pass it to the `img` tag

```
<img  src=imagePath/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify all your JavaScript variables inside `<script>.....</script>` tags if placed in same file. So you cant do like this. Although you can freely change any `attribute - value` from script.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want. If so you have update VarId3 and image src in javascript

```js
var VarId3 = 0;
function updateImage(){
  document.getElementById("myImage").src = "Images\Status" + VarId3 + ".png";
  if(VarId3 == 0) VarId3 = 1;
  else VarId3 = 0;
}
```

```html
<img  src="" id="myImage"/>
<button onclick="updateImage()"></button>
```